# Deserializing a Java object

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm interfacing with a C++ server so i decided to de-/serialize my objects into an XML string that I send over the socket.

I can't use a custom library, because on the server side, I can't install big libraries, as the space is rather limited, so the code should be as small as possible.

So far I have written a first version of serializing my objects via reflection which was pretty easy to do. Currently I use only `int` and `String`, but i want to use this as a foundation to extend later, so I would like to get the base right as much as possible.

Now when I serialize into an XML the values are of course in a string representation (here is an example how it looks):

```
<serializable classname="client.ServerTask">
    <member classname="int" isnull="false" name="mTaskId" primitive="true">
        <value>
            <![CDATA[35]]>
        </value>
    </member>
    <member classname="java.lang.String" isnull="false" name="mName" primitive="false">
        <value>
            <![CDATA[TestServer]]>
        </value>
    </member>
    <member classname="int" isnull="false" name="mPID" primitive="true">
        <value>
            <![CDATA[512]]>
        </value>
    </member>
    <member classname="int" isnull="false" name="mStatus" primitive="true">
        <value>
            <![CDATA[32768]]>
        </value>
    </member>
</serializable>
```

Now I'm trying to implement the desrialization and I'm facing the problem of getting the values back from a string into the actual values.

For primitives and the string class this is trivial, but I wonder what to do about custom classes later on.

I was thinking that, if I recursevily go down into member classes, it should boil down to primitves all the way, or am I wrong there? I set up the serialization in such a way that I could recursevily serialize members and subclasses which are not primitive or strings.

Am I missing something or is my understanding correct? If I would do it like this, would I be able to desirialize properly also complex classes?

Currently I'm ignoring the problem of references, as the first step would be to deserialize a straight, simple class only.

Comment: does your program must deserialize in XML? If not, then other format such as JSON could be a better choice since it makes the serializing and deserializing easier.

Comment: I was choosing XML, because it is already on our server system and so it is one of the external libraries that I can actually use without putting it in my local space. Also I wanted to get experience with XML as we are using that quite a lot in other projects, so it was the natural choice for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard solution to this is [JAXB](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/), which has been [part of Java SE since JDK 1.6](https://jaxb.java.net/guide/Which_JAXB_RI_is_included_in_which_JDK_.html).

In particular, it supports configuring the mapping with annotations (or you can simply rely on the sensible default values), which is far less verbose than an external XML file, and can derive mapped classes from an XML Schema, or a Schema from the mapped classes. It can also easily validate documents against an XML Schema.

Additionally, if the XML you are consuming is a SOAP webservice, JAX-WS builds on JAXB to create interfaces from a WSDL (or a WSDL from an annotated interface), and transpararently handles the marshalling and unmarshalling for you.

Comment: Yes, I know about JAXB, but it requires additional tools to install and this I have to avoid.

Comment: What "tools"? It is part of any recent JDK, how are you developing Java without one?

Comment: AFAIK I have to install this additional compiler to generate the classes, right?

Comment: Using xjc.exe is optional, and by virtue of being part of every JDK released in the last couple years (for instance, jdk1.6.0_02\bin\xjc.exe), is very likely to be already installed anyway ...

Comment: OK. I guess I should take a closer look then. I was reading the intro and maybe I got a wrong idea.mI have to see if JDK 1.6 is installed there as well. Might be that we only have 1.5.

Comment: I googled quite a lot for tutorials on JAXB and they all looked rather complicated to me, as I didn't want to deal with XSD. Finally I found a simple one here (http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/) which exactly showed what I wanted. After doing some test now I found that, for the simple case to get me started, the code is not more complicated then using XMLEncoder, without the disadvantages I noticed, so i decided to go with JAXB. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use XMLEncoder/XMLDecoder, it's part of JDK.

Check: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html

BTW, you said you are interfacing with a c++ server, how do you de-serialize the xml on there? Have matched c++ classes?

Seems you are reinvent some cross language RPC/communication mechanism. Did your look at "Java RMI" or SOAP Based Web Service?

Comment: Currently I doing it manually on the server side. I know this is a pain, but I was looking at JAXB and I must install many tools additionally for this, so this is not something I can use. :( I will look what this `RMI` and `SOAP` is, as I haven't found this before.

Comment: Just tested it and the XMLEncoder looks perfect for my needs. Thanks!